# How to find an element with respect to its parent element with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape a website, but I need to search for an element whose parent is like this:

```
//div[@title="parent"]
```

People are talking about getting an element from its child. Is there a way to reverse it and find the child from its parent?

I want the `/span` with `@title = "child"` whose parent is `//div[@title = "Search results."]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use

```
//div[parent::div[@title="parent"]]
```

or simply

```
//div[@title="parent"]/div
```

In Python code you can also use

```
parent = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@title="parent"]')
child = parent.find_element(By.XPATH, './div')
```

Comment: Is this supposed to give me all the elements whose parent is this ?

Comment: @OmarYacop yes. Do you need a specific node?

Comment: @OmarYacop then `'//div[parent::div[@title="parent"]]'` should work

Comment: I want the /span with @title = "child" whose parent is //div[@title = "Search results."]

Comment: @OmarYacop `//span[@title='child' and parent::div[@title='parent']]`

Answer (score 1):

To locate the child element:

```
<span title="child"...>
```

within it's parent:

```
<div title="Search results."...>
```

you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[title='Search results.'] span[title='child']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Search results.']//span[@title='child']")
  ```